# Redmine: Missing a field to put the Git repository path

Tags: git, integration, redmine

I'm not sure what I'm missing but after setting up Redmine and locally "git cloned" a repo using "--mirror" option. I wanted to put the Git repo path into Redmine, but the Redmine -> Settings -> Repo page doesn't seem to have a place for me to put that path. Am I missing anything? (See attached screenshots below for better illustration of this issue)

I followed this guide except I skip the Subversion/Mercurial part:
[HowTo Install Redmine 1.2.x with Mercurial and Subversion on Ubuntu Server 10.04](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowToInstallRedmineOnUbuntuServer)

Also followed this Apache configuration for Git in Redmine guide:[Repositories access control with apache, mod_dav_svn and mod_perl](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Repositories_access_control_with_apache_mod_dav_svn_and_mod_perl)

Also try to get the Git repo setup locally using this guide:
[Repositories](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineRepositories)

I wanted to setup like it did in this blog post:
[Configuring a Git repository with Redmine](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/07/configuring-git-repository-with-redmine/)

**What it suppose look like**:
[image: What it suppose look like]

**What it actually look like in my setup**:
[image: What it actually look like in my setup]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your second screenshot is the settings page of your redmine *installation* - the settings here apply to all projects. However, you can't link a repository from there.

You should make sure that you created a project, and then go into the project's settings page. There you'll find the Repository settings of your first screenshot.